# Finding address of OLED using I2C communication and Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, ssd1306, oled

It is known that address of OLED SSD1306 is 3C. The frame format is as follows:
[image]

The figure implies that the binary pattern should be 01111000 for the first frame (considering write mode and the second last bit is a dont care).
So I was trying to send the first frame using Wire.h library. The following is a code
`Wire.beginTransmission(0b01111001);`
But i receive a nack (return value of 2)

However, If I send 00111100, i receive a ack(return value of 0). What is wrong in my interpretation?

Comment: You should scan the bus, maybe the display has a different address. You can use this sketch: https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner/

Comment: I referred to this link. It shows the address is 3c but that should not be the case because the above pic is of ssd1306 datasheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misinterpret how the `Wire` library is used. Though the first byte in the transmission is called the address byte, the actual address consists only of the 7 higher bits in that byte. The direction bit is not in the address.

So the `Wire.beginTransmission()` method wants the address as parameter, without the direction bit. That bit is set corresponding to the used function (0 for `Wire.beginTransmission()` and 1 for `Wire.requestFrom()`).

`0b0111100` is the real address (when connnecting the address pin to ground)(note, that there are only 7 bits, since the address only has 7 bits). The write operation address byte will then be `0b01111000`, though the library is hiding that way from you. You need to provide the 7 bit address to the function.

> the second last bit is a dont care

As mentioned above, that is not correct. This bit (the least significant bit of the address) is set by the address pin SA0. It seems, that you have it tied to ground, which sets the corresponding bit in the address to zero. If you would tie it to Vcc, it would be 1.

Comment: I understand where I was wrong. Thank you. However, I have one more question. How do I send the read/write bit??

Comment: @shivamag000 as chrisl wrote you don't manually send it. The read/write bit is automatically handled by `Wire.startTransmission()` (clears the bit to address the slave in write mode) and `Wire.requestFrom()` (sets the bit to address the slave in read mode). It's important to only use the 7-bit address, preferably in another format than binary, which can be a bit confusing

Comment: Yes, the data direction bit is handled by the library. When you use the write functions (`Wire.beginTransmission()` and `Wire.endTransmission()`) it will use zero for the direction bit. If you use the read function `Wire.requestFrom()`, it will use 1 for the direction bit.

Comment: Also keep in mind, that the actual transmission is done in `Wire.endTransmission()`. Before that no data will be transmitted.

Comment: Thank you @chrisl

Answer (score 0):

I2C has a 7-bit address space. The device's actual address is `0b0111100` (=0x3c). The sequences `0b01111001` and `0b01111000` address the same slave while the first one (least significant bit is `1`) starts a read transmission, the second one starts a write transmission.

Those least significant bits are nothing you need to care about when using `Wire.h`: the mode of operation is automatically set when using `Wire.startTransmission(addr)` (returns `0` when slave ACK'ed write command) and `Wire.requestFrom(addr)` (returns `0` when slave ACK'ed read command).

Comment: Even if I send ```0b01111000```, a nack is received

Comment: @shivamag000 that's not what you wrote in your question ("However, If I send 00111100, i receive a ack") and a return value of 0 means that the slave ACK'ed

Comment: @shivamag000 also, `0b01111000` is not what you are supposed to pass to `Wire.beginTransmission()`. It takes the **7**-bit address. You better don't mess with binary format, simply do `Wire.beginTransmission(0x3c)`...

Comment: can you please show the reference where it says that wire.begin takes seven bit addresses

Comment: @shivamag000 https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireBeginTransmission

Comment: Thank you @Sim son